# How to control the font size in figures based on required figure size in R?

Tags: r, pdf, figure

I'm producing figures for Nature, which requires the figure size of either 89mm (single column) or 183mm (double column). The label should be 8pt bold, and the text should be 7 pt.

I'm using R to produce figures, but I don't know how to control the exact figure size (i.e. in 89 mm) while control the exact font size (i.e. 7pt).

This is what I have now for output a pdf figure:

```
pdf(file='filename.pdf',width=6.5,height=3.5)
  par(ps=10)
  ....
dev.off()
```

I also used `cex` in the `plot` function to control the font size. But how to relate `cex` with 'pt'?

Thanks!
Katie

Comment: Have you tried using the `pointsize` argument to the `pdf()` function?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Just actually get to work on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks to [Jean V. Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140956/jean-v-adams) for his reply. Let me just summarise the way to specify both font size and graph size in a nutshell:

If the requirement (for example *Nature*) is graph width `183mm` (for 2-column width), font size is `7pt`, and line width should between `0.25pt` to `1pt`, then you specify the parameter as follows and pass them to your plot:

```
# mm to inch
setWidth = 183*0.039370 

# font size in pt
setFontSize = 7

# 1 in R = 0.75pt, so 0.25pt is specified as 
setLwd <- 0.25/0.75    


pdf(file='filename.pdf',width=setWidth,height=3.5,pointsize=setFontSize)
plot(x,y,lwd=setLwd)
.....
dev.off()
```

If you have other smart tricks please append to this, would appreciate it!